# Chrome fails to size svg element (nvd3) properly in flexbox

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, flexbox, nvd3.js

In the following setting, when running Chrome 49, the `svg` element fails to adapt to the parent `div`'s size. Firefox 43 works fine though.

```
<style>
.display-flex {
  display:  -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:  -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}

<div class="display-flex">
  <div style="background-color: #ccc">Lorem ipsum dolor....</div>
  <div id="chart" style="min-width: 250px; background-color: #999">
    <svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%"/>
  </div>
```

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMCVR.png)

What can be seen from above screenshots is the fact that the `div` element itself is properly sized, both in Firefox and Chrome.

Remedies (all of which are not necessary in Firefox) that I tried in Chrome without success:

1. include normalize.js to address potential user agent style influence
2. set <svg> width/height style to 100%
3. upgrade to latest nvd3 version 1.8.3

One thing that is necessary in Firefox however is this:

```
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
```

It, too, fails to do the trick in Chrome.

If you want to check it out for yourself:

http://output.jsbin.com/votahimure/1

Comment: one workaround is to set the parent position to relative and the svg's one to absolute. http://jsbin.com/hugomijuxu/1 But I'd like to know why it does it and which UA is right if any.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, that works in both browsers. I'm also interested in the reason and potential cure for that inconsistency though.

Comment: It's like one UA (FF) does create a new stack for the svg node, while the other (chrome) doesn't.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you so much!! No one wrote this in whole internet except you!